# Is it possible to safely mix javascript class styles in an inheritance tree

Tags: javascript

I have picked up a piece of software which is fairly old and it has this form of "class" definition

```
function thisThing(parm1, parm2)
{
    var self = new BaseThing(parm1);
    self.val2 = parm2;
    self.function2 = function() { ... }
    return self;
}
```

I'd like to convert the whole hierachy to use the `thisThing.prototype` style of class, something like this

```
function thisThing(parm1, parm2)
{
    var self = new BaseThing(parm1);
    self.val2 = parm2;
    return self;
}

thisThing.prototype = Object.create(BaseThing.prototype);
thisThing.prototype.constructor = thisThing;

thisThing.prototype = {
    function2() { ... }
}
```

but I'm not sure if it is safe to mix the two styles.

Do I have to convert the whole hierarchy at once? Or can I do it a class at a time, and in which case do I need to do it top up, bottom down, or can I do it in the order I come across classes?

A note: Please don't suggest using ES6 classes, as they are not available in my current environment.

Comment: Sorry, mistranscribed the function

Comment: In the original class the 'return self' was about 500 lines below the rest of it, so I missed that, apologies.

Comment: How is `thisThing` currently called? `t = new thisThing(1, 2);` or `t = thisThing(1, 2);`?

Comment: The form you've shown as what you'd like to switch to is quite non-standard, and `thisThing.prototype` is never used in it. Did you mean you want to use standard JavaScript constructor functions?

Comment: it's called as "t = new thisThing(1, 2)". 

Sorry, I have got typo fever this morning. i shouldnt have chosen 'function1' as a function name. Why is the 2nd form nonstandard?

One reason Id like to change is I've seen a lot of comments about the 1st form being not terribly efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've said that the old `thisThing` is called via `new`, which is good news in terms of whether you can mix things together (although we could work around it if not).

What you've shown as your desired form is quite non-standard, and `thisThing.prototype` is never used in it. I'm going to assume you mean you want to use standard constructor functions, which look like this:

```
function ThisThing(parm1, parm2) {
    BaseThing.call(this, parm1);
    this.parm2 = parm2;
}
ThisThing.prototype = Object.create(BaseThing.prototype);
ThisThing.prototype.constructor = ThisThing;
ThisThing.prototype.someMethod = function() {
    // ...
};
```

Based on what you have in the question, you can go ahead and do that. (I do recommend the change in capitalization, it's the overwhelming standard for constructor functions.)

If there's any chance code might be calling it *without* `new`, you can make it tolerate that by detecting what's happened and handing off to `new` in the constructor:

```
function ThisThing(parm1, parm2) {
    if (!(this instanceof ThisThing)) {
        // Called without `new`; handle it
        return new ThisThing(parm1, parm2);
    }
    BaseThing.call(this, parm1);
    this.parm2 = parm2;
}
// ...
```

The `thisThing` you showed was using `BaseThing` as a constructor, so I assume (from that and the name) that it's already using the constructor pattern above.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to replace it like this. The only issue might be setting the param1 is a `new BaseThing`, so you might need to modify your old code.

by doing this you are using prototypical inheritance to get the methods of `BaseThing`.

Conversion like this can be mixed with your existing code with no problems so you can change one class at a time.

```
function ThisThing(param1, param2) {
  this.val1 = param1
  this.val2 = param2
}

ThisThing.prototype = new BaseThing

ThisThing.prototype.function2 = function() {}

var thing = new ThisThing(1, 2)

console.log(
  thing instanceof BaseThing, // => true
  thing instanceof ThisThing  // => true
)
```